# Determining size of SharePoint sites / site collections

Tags: sharepoint, stsadm

I'm about to start googling but figured I'd start here.  We already found a [VB script](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Recursively-listing-all-MOSS-Site-Collections-and-Sub-Sites.aspx) that enumerates SharePoint site collections / sites.  It calls stsadm to achieve this and it recursively evaluates each site to get the sub-sites.

I would like to know if we can modify that script to get the size (in bytes) of each site collection / site.

We're using MOSS 2007.

**EDIT**:
I found a [related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226117/sts-adm-command-for-moss-2007) but didn't see an answer for the disk space question.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the site collection's size in MB.

```
stsadm -o enumsites -url http://url

<Sites Count="1">
  <Site 
    Url="http://url" 
    Owner="A\user" 
    SecondaryOwner="A\user2" 
    ContentDatabase="WSS_Content_DB"
    StorageUsedMB="13756" 
    StorageWarningMB="0"
    StorageMaxMB="0" />
</Sites>
```

Will update if I find a method for sites/subsites.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this information from Central Admin. Application Management > Site Collection Quota and Locks. At the bottom it gets you the spaces used currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the total disk / db usage on the site settings page, not sure how to achieve this per site though, I think STSADM.exe -o enumsites -url htt://siteurl sites.txt exports an xml file with size included

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax to export http://example.com to c:\sites.txt

```
stsadm - o enumsites -url "http://example.com" > c:\sites.txt
```